# PHP form not working when loaded with JQuery .load()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, post

I'm working on a small table based software that runs within the browser.
I needed to add a search bar and I was able to do that using JQuery .load() to load a PHP file with the table and the right MySQL SELECT instructions, corresponding to the user text input.
However, when I do that, all the forms to update the rows data become empty (checked with JQuery .serialize()) and they do not send anything to POST.
This is the code of the main PHP file with the table: https://expirebox.com/download/e70d6f84dd7964c16ff20bcf6ffababd.html

This is the JS code of the previous PHP page:

```
var vistaF = true;

$(document).keydown(function(event) 
{
    if (event.which==70) 
    {
        if (vistaF)
        {
            $("th, td").css("border", "none");
            vistaF = false;
        }
        else
        {
            $("th, td").css("border", "1px solid grey");
            vistaF = true;
        }
    }
});

function controllaContesto(id)
{
    if (id=="r")
    {
        var ricerca = "ricerca-";
        id = "";
    }
    else
    {
        var ricerca = "";
        id = "-"+id;
    }

    if ($("#"+ricerca+"contesto"+id+" option:selected").text()=="fiera")
    {
        $("#contenitore-"+ricerca+"fiera"+id).css("display", "inline");
    }
    else
    {
        if ((inizio || $("#contenitore-"+ricerca+"fiera"+id).attr("style")=="display: inline;") && $("#contenitore-"+ricerca+"fiera"+id).val()!=undefined)
        {
            $("#contenitore-"+ricerca+"fiera"+id).css("display", "none");
        }
    }
}

function ricerca()
{
    var cerca = $("#ricerca input[type='text']").val();
    var accessoDb = true;
    if ($("#opzioniAvanzate").css("display")=="none")
    {
        var ricercaIntelligente = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        var ricercaIntelligente = 0;
    }
    var opzioni = new Array();
    $("input[name='campo-cerca']:checked").each(function(){opzioni.push(this.value);});
    if (opzioni[0]==undefined)
    {
        opzioni[0] = 0;
    }
    var filtri = new Array();
    filtri[0] = $("#ricerca-listino").val();
    filtri[1] = $("#ricerca-contesto").val();
    filtri[2] = $("#ricerca-fiera").val();
    filtri[3] = $("#ricerca-utente").val();

    if (accessoDb)
    {
        accessoDb = false;
        setTimeout(function(){$("table").load("ricerca-risposte.php", {cerca: cerca, ricercaIntelligente: ricercaIntelligente, opzioni: opzioni, filtri: filtri});}, 500);
        inizio = true;
        setTimeout(function(){accessoDb = true;}, 2000);
    }
}

function mostraOpzioniAvanzate()
{
    if ($("#opzioniAvanzate").css("display")=="none")
    {
        $("#opzioniAvanzate").css("display", "block");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#opzioniAvanzate").css("display", "none");
        $("#opzioniAvanzate").children("input[type='checkbox']").each(function()
        {
            if ($(this).attr("id")=="radio-cliente")
            {
                if ($(this).prop("checked")==false)
                { 
                    $(this).prop("checked", true);
                    ricerca();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if ($(this).prop("checked")==true)
                { 
                    $(this).prop("checked", false);
                    ricerca();
                }
            }
        });
        $("#opzioniAvanzate").children("select").each(function()
        {
            if ($(this).val()!=0)
            { 
                $("#"+$(this).attr("id")+" option:eq(0)").prop("selected", true);
                ricerca();
            }
        });
        if ($("#ricerca-fiera").val()!=0)
        {
            $("#ricerca-fiera option:eq(0)").prop("selected", true);
            controllaContesto("r");
        }
    }
}

function comandiTestoSI(id, risolto)
{   
    $("#sfondoTestoSI").mousedown(function(event) 
    {
        if (event.which==1) 
        {
            $("#testoSI").css("display", "none");
            $("#sfondoTestoSI").css("display", "none");
            $("table").removeClass("sfuocato");
            if (!risolto && $("#testoSI").val().trim()!="" && $("#testo-"+id).html()!=$("#testoSI").val())
            {
                var temp = $("#testoSI").val();
                $("#testo-"+id).html(temp);

                var lunghezzaMax = 100;
                var limite = 0;

                if (temp.length>lunghezzaMax)
                {
                    limite = lunghezzaMax;
                }
                var posTemp = temp.indexOf("\n");
                if (posTemp!=-1)
                {
                    posTemp = temp.indexOf("\n", posTemp+1);
                    if (posTemp!=-1)
                    {
                        limite = posTemp+5;
                    }
                    temp = temp.replace("\n", "<br />");
                }
                if (limite==0)
                {
                    $("#"+id).html(temp);
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#"+id).html(temp.substr(0, limite)+"...");
                }
            }
        }
    });
}


function chiamaTestoSI(id, risolto)
{
        $("#testoSI").css("display", "block");
        $("#sfondoTestoSI").css("display", "block");
        if (risolto)
        {
            $("#testoSI").attr("readonly", "readonly");
        }
        else if ($("#testoSI").attr("readonly")=="readonly")
        {
            $("#testoSI").removeAttr("readonly");
        }
        $("table").attr("class", "sfuocato");
        $("#testoSI").val($("#testo-"+id).html());
        comandiTestoSI(id, risolto);
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    for (index=0; index<id.length; index++)
    {
        controllaContesto(id[index]);
    }
    controllaContesto("r");
    inizio = false;
    $("#ricerca input[type='text']").on("keyup input", function()
    {
        ricerca();
    });
    $("#ricerca button").click(function()
    {
        if (!$("#ricerca input[type='text']").val().trim()=="")
        {
            ricerca();
        }
    });
    $("#opzioniAvanzate input").change(ricerca);
    $("#opzioniAvanzate select").change(ricerca);
});
```

And last but not least, here is the PHP code of the file that is called with JQuery .load() from the ricerca() function:

```
<?php
require('lib/php/dbManager.php');
require('lib/php/dbConfig.php');
require('lib/php/dbQuery.php');

$db_risposte = new dbManager(host, user, password, dbName);
$mostra = false;

$cerca = $_POST['cerca'];
$ricercaIntelligente = $_POST['ricercaIntelligente'];
$opzioni = $_POST['opzioni'];
$filtri = $_POST['filtri'];

$db_risposte->run('SELECT id, nome FROM contesti');
while($val = $db_risposte->get())
{
    $contesti['id'][] = $val['id'];
    $contesti['nome'][] = $val['nome'];
}
$db_risposte->run('SELECT id, nome FROM fiere');
while($val = $db_risposte->get())
{
    $fiere['id'][] = $val['id'];
    $fiere['nome'][] = $val['nome'];
}

if ($ricercaIntelligente==1)
{
    function ricercaIntelligente($filtro, $numFiltro)
    {
        global $filtri, $cerca;

        for ($indice=0; $indice<count($filtro); $indice++)
        {
            if (strpos(strtolower($filtro['nome'][$indice]), strtolower($cerca))!==false)
            {
                $filtri[$numFiltro] = $filtro['id'][$indice];
                $cerca = '';
                return true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    if (strlen($cerca)>2)
    {
        if (!ricercaIntelligente($contesti, 1))
        {
            ricercaIntelligente($fiere, 2);
        }
    }
}

function scriviQuery($cerca, $opzioni, $filtri)
{   
    function tempFunz($tabella, $valore, &$primo, $colonna)
    {
        global $db_risposte;
        $parteQuery = '';

        $db_risposte->run('SELECT id FROM '.$tabella.' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1');
        while($val = $db_risposte->get())
        {
            $maxIndice = $val['id'];
        }
        for ($indice=1; $indice<=$maxIndice; $indice++)
        {
            if ($valore==$indice)
            {

                if ($primo)
                {
                    $parteQuery .= ' WHERE IF (risposte.'.$colonna.'=\'0\', richieste.'.$colonna.', risposte.'.$colonna.')=\''.$indice.'\'';
                    $primo = false;
                }
                else
                {

                    $parteQuery .= ' AND IF (risposte.'.$colonna.'=\'0\', richieste.'.$colonna.', risposte.'.$colonna.')=\''.$indice.'\'';
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        return $parteQuery;
    }

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM richieste INNER JOIN risposte ON richieste.id = risposte.id';
    $primo = true;

    for ($indice=0; $indice<count($opzioni); $indice++)
    {
        switch (true)
        {
            case ($opzioni[$indice]==1):
                if ($primo)
                {
                    $query .= ' WHERE richieste.cliente LIKE \'%'.$cerca.'%\'';
                    $primo = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    $query .= ' AND richieste.cliente LIKE \'%'.$cerca.'%\'';
                }
                break;
            case ($opzioni[$indice]==2):
                if ($primo)
                {
                    $query .= ' WHERE IF (risposte.fattura=\'0\', richieste.fattura, risposte.fattura) LIKE \'%'.$cerca.'%\'';
                    $primo = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    $query .= ' AND IF (risposte.fattura=\'0\', richieste.fattura, risposte.fattura) LIKE \'%'.$cerca.'%\'';
                }
                break;
            case ($opzioni[$indice]==3):
                if ($primo)
                {
                    $query .= ' WHERE risposte.causale LIKE \'%'.$cerca.'%\'';
                    $primo = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    $query .= ' AND risposte.causale LIKE \'%'.$cerca.'%\'';
                }
                break;
            case ($opzioni[$indice]==4):
                if ($primo)
                {
                    $query .= ' WHERE risposte.oggetto LIKE \'%'.$cerca.'%\'';
                    $primo = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    $query .= ' AND risposte.oggetto LIKE \'%'.$cerca.'%\'';
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    if ($filtri[0]!=0)
    {
        $query .= tempFunz('listini', $filtri[0], $primo, 'listino');
    }
    if ($filtri[1]!=0)
    {
        $query .= tempFunz('contesti', $filtri[1], $primo, 'contesto');
    }
    if ($filtri[2]!=0)
    {
        $query .= tempFunz('fiere', $filtri[2], $primo, 'fiera');
    }
    if ($filtri[3]!=0)
    {
        $query .= tempFunz('utenti', $filtri[3], $primo, 'utente');
    }

    return $query;
}

$query = scriviQuery($cerca, $opzioni, $filtri);

function getDataFromDB()
{
    global $db_risposte, $mostra, $id, $data, $fattura, $causale, $oggetto, $listino, $contesto, $fiera, $utente, $risolto, $vistaSingola, $query, $vistaRisolto, $cliente;
    $id = array();
    $data = array();
    $fattura = array();
    $causale = array();
    $oggetto = array();
    $listino = array();
    $contesto = array();
    $fiera = array();
    $utente = array();
    $risolto = array();

    $db_risposte->run($query);
    while($val = $db_risposte->get())
    {
        $mostra = true;
        $id[] = $val['id'];
        $data[] = $val['data'];
        $fattura[] = $val['fattura'];
        $causale[] = $val['causale'];
        $oggetto[] = $val['oggetto'];
        $listino[] = $val['listino'];
        $contesto[] = $val['contesto'];
        $fiera[] = $val['fiera'];
        $utente[] = $val['utente'];
        $risolto[] = $val['risolto'];
    }

    for ($index=0; $index<count($id); $index++)
    {
        $query = 'SELECT cliente, fattura, listino, contesto, fiera, utente FROM richieste WHERE id=\''.$id[$index].'\'';
        $db_risposte->run($query);
        while($val = $db_risposte->get())
        {
            $cliente[] = $val['cliente'];
            if ($fattura[$index]==0)
            {
                $fattura[$index] = $val['fattura'];
            }
            if ($listino[$index]==0)
            {
                $listino[$index] = $val['listino'];
            }
            if ($contesto[$index]==0)
            {
                $contesto[$index] = $val['contesto'];
            }
            if ($contesto[$index]==0)
            {
                $contesto[$index] = $val['contesto'];
            }
            if (associaNome('contesti', $contesto[$index])=='fiera' && $fiera[$index]==0)
            {
                $fiera[$index] = $val['fiera'];
            }
            if ($utente[$index]==0)
            {
                $utente[$index] = $val['utente'];
            }
        }
    }
}

getDataFromDB();

function inputTesto($risolto, $val, $nameInput=null)
{
    $html = '';

    if ($risolto==0)
    {
        $html .= '<input type="text" name="'.$nameInput.'" value="'.$val.'"/>';
    }
    else
    {
        $html .= '<p>'.$val.'</p>';
    }

    return $html;
}

function anteprimaStringa($stringa, $lunghezza)
{
    $limite = strlen($stringa);
    $puntini = '';

    if (strlen($stringa)>=$lunghezza)
    {
        $limite = $lunghezza;
        $puntini = '...';

    }
    $posTemp = strpos($stringa, '<br />');
    if ($posTemp!==false)
    {
        $posTemp = strpos($stringa, '<br />', $posTemp+6);
        if ($posTemp!==false)
        {
            $limite = $posTemp;
            if ($puntini=='')
            {
                $puntini = '...';
            }
        }
    }

    return substr($stringa, 0, $limite).$puntini;
}

function textarea($risolto, $val, $nameInput=null, $id=null)
{
    $html = '';
    if ($val=='')
    {
        $val = 'CLICCAMI PER MODIFICARE!';
    }

    $html .= '<p id="';
    if ($nameInput=='causale')
    {
        $html .= 'causale';
    }
    else if ($nameInput=='oggetto')
    {
        $html .= 'oggetto';
    }
    $html .= '-'.$id.'" class="anteprima" onclick="javascript:chiamaTestoSI(this.id, ';
    if ($risolto==0)
    {
        $html .= 'false';
    }
    else
    {
        $html .= 'true';
    }
    $html .= ')">';
    $html .= anteprimaStringa($val, 97);
    $html .= '</p>';
    $html .= '<textarea id="testo-';
    if ($nameInput=='causale')
    {
        $html .= 'causale';
    }
    else if ($nameInput=='oggetto')
    {
        $html .= 'oggetto';
    } 
    $html .= '-'.$id.'" name="'.$nameInput.'" style="display: none;" >'.str_replace('<br />', '', $val).'</textarea>';

    return $html;
}

function associaNome($nomeTabella, $id)
{
    global $db_risposte;
    $nome = '';

    $query = 'SELECT nome FROM '.$nomeTabella.' WHERE id=\''.$id.'\'';
    $db_risposte->run($query);
    while($val = $db_risposte->get())
    {
        $nome .= $val['nome'];
    }

    return $nome;
}

function opzioni($risolto, $nomeTabella, $selected, $nameSelect=null, $idSelect=null, $onchangeJS=null)
{
    global $db_risposte;
    $html = '';
    if ($idSelect===null)
    {
        $idSelect = '';
    }
    if ($onchangeJS===null)
    {
        $onchangeJS = '';
    }

    if ($risolto==0)
    {
        if ($nomeTabella=='fiere')
        {
            $html .= '<span id="contenitore-'.$idSelect.'">: ';
        }
        $html .= '<select name="'.$nameSelect.'"';
        if ($idSelect!='')
        {
            $html .= ' id="'.$idSelect.'"';
        }
        if ($onchangeJS!='')
        {
            $html .= ' onchange="javascript:'.$onchangeJS.'"';
        }
        $html .= '>';
        $query = 'SELECT id FROM '.$nomeTabella.' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1';
        $db_risposte->run($query);
        while($val = $db_risposte->get())
        {
            $idMax = $val['id'];
        }

        for ($index=1; $index<=$idMax; $index++)
        {
            $html .= '<option value="'.$index.'"';

            if ($index==$selected)
            {
                $html .= ' selected';
            }
            $html .= '>';

            $html .= associaNome($nomeTabella, $index);

            $html .= '</option>';
        }
        $html .= '</select>';
        if ($nomeTabella=='fiere')
        {
            $html .= '</span>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        switch(true)
        {
            case($nomeTabella=='contesti' && associaNome($nomeTabella, $selected)=='fiera'):
                $html .= '<p>';
                $html .= associaNome($nomeTabella, $selected);
                $html .= ': ';
                break;
            case($nomeTabella=='fiere'):
                $html .= associaNome($nomeTabella, $selected);
                $html .= '</p>';
                break;
            default:
                $html .= '<p>';
                $html .= associaNome($nomeTabella, $selected);
                $html .= '</p>';
                break;
        }


    }

    return $html;
}
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th><h1>id</h1></th>
        <th><h1>data</h1></th> 
        <th><h1>cliente</h1></th> 
        <th><h1>fattura</h1></th>
        <th><h1>causale</h1></th>
        <th><h1>oggetto</h1></th>
        <th><h1>listino</h1></th>
        <th><h1>contesto</h1></th>
        <th><h1>utente</h1></th>
        <th><h1>risolto</h1></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
<?php
    if ($mostra)
    {
        for ($index=0; $index<count($id); $index++)
        {
            if ($risolto[$index]=='1')
            {
                $classe = 'class="risolto"';
            }
            else
            {
                $classe = '';
            }
            ?>
            <tr id="<?php echo($id[$index]) ?>" <?php echo($classe) ?>>
                <form action="risposte.php?id=<?php echo($id[$index]); ?>" method="post">
                    <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo($id[$index]) ?>"/>
                    <th><p><?php echo($id[$index]); ?></p></th>
                    <th><p><?php if ($data[$index]!='0000-00-00 00:00:00'){echo(date("m/d/Y H:i:s", strtotime($data[$index])));} else {echo('00/00/0000 00:00:00');} ?></p></th>
                    <th><p><?php echo($cliente[$index]); ?></p></th>
                    <th><?php echo(inputTesto($risolto[$index], $fattura[$index], 'fattura')); ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo(textarea($risolto[$index], $causale[$index], 'causale', $id[$index])); ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo(textarea($risolto[$index], $oggetto[$index], 'oggetto', $id[$index])); ?></th>
                    <th>
                        <?php echo(opzioni($risolto[$index], 'listini', $listino[$index], 'listino')); ?>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <?php echo(opzioni($risolto[$index], 'contesti', $contesto[$index], 'contesto', 'contesto-'.$id[$index], 'controllaContesto('.$id[$index].')')); echo(opzioni($risolto[$index], 'fiere', $fiera[$index], 'fiera', 'fiera-'.$id[$index])); ?>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <?php echo(opzioni($risolto[$index], 'utenti', $utente[$index], 'utente')); ?>
                    </th>
                    <?php
                    if ($risolto[$index]=='1')
                    {
                        ?>
                        <th><p>sì</p></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <?php
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    ?>
                    <th><input name="risolto" type="checkbox" value="s"/></th>
                    <th><input type="submit" value="AGGIORNA"/></th>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </form>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    }
?>
</table>
```

Please, help me.
Thank you very much.

Comment: This is a little too generic and definitely not constructive. You are basically saying that something does not work in your project and asking someone to understand what and find a solution. I've given a quick look at your code and I suggest you split the various pieces of your program and selectively exclude them as you check that they work well, to isolate the problem. When you know exactly what block is creating the issue, you can write it back here and it will be so much easier to help (though I think that by then, having the problem clear, you might be able to solve it without any help).

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: I know it is, but I don't care since it's just a small app for internal use. It's not even on the Internet, it's on our small server.
@Plastic I understand that my problem is a bit vague, but unfortunately I was not able to identify the cause. I checked Google and Stack Overflow as well. Sorry, I'll think more about it.

Comment: I only see the input risolto, and where php form handling?

Comment: "It's not even on the Internet, it's on our small server.". Doesn't matter. You can't be 100% certain you can trust your users just because they're _your_ users - you don't really know their personality, skills or their motivations fully (esp if they become discontented, for instance), nor do you know the junk they may have installed on their machines either, or anything else that could get into the network. Plus it's just good practice to do it right from the beginning, it's not particularly difficult or onerous. In fact there's really no good reason _not_ to write queries securely.

Comment: @ADyson I thought very much about what you said and in the end I decided to sanitize all inputs. Thank you again for the help. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to thank all of you for pushing me to find an answer on my own.
I did it: I solved the problem, but I still don't know what created the issue in the first place.
Apparently using JQuery .load() makes the browser confused about what is inside my forms and what is not. Therefore I took advantage of the new HTML5 attribute which connects form elements to a specific form id.
[HTML form Attribute - W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form.asp)
Now everything is working just fine.
My only question is why the problem was created by that JQuery method and why I did not need the form attribute before using the AJAX load function?